# Do something when a Chef Data Bag Changes

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

Is there a way to do something when the values change in a Chef Data Bag.

Lets say a data bag looks like this.

```
{
    "data": {
        "version": "1.0.12-SNAPSHOT"
    }
}
```

and it changes to this

```
{
    "data": {
        "version": "1.0.13"
    }
}
```

is there a way for a Chef resource to 'Subscribe' to this change or this change to 'Notify' a Resource of the change?

Comment: Using open source chef server or enterprise chef?

Comment: I am using enterprise chef.

Comment: Then it's not a clear no. I don't know, if you can already trigger a push job on an event like a data bag upload in enterprise chef. But such a [push job](http://docs.opscode.com/push_jobs.html) could then trigger chef-client.

Answer (score 2):

The common solution for this is *not* to subscribe to the change in the data bag but to sensibly handle the result of the change.

It seems that you describe a version of a software to be installed there. Thus, a sensible approach would be to perform these steps during each chef run:

- check if the currently installed version of the software is the same as the one currently defined in the data bag
- if it matches, do nothing
- if it differs, update the software

That way, you don't need any actual publish/subscribe architecture but just handle everything during your regular chef runs.

In fact, this general approach is how about all providers in Chef work: check the current state and adapt it if it differs from the intended state as defined by the recipe.

Comment: ok I get this.  Is there a 'chef' way of keeping tabs on what software is installed on a node or do you have to bake your own solution to do that? I can think of things like writing out a file with the versions and then reading from that....or grep the processes to get the versions....both sound a little problematic....wonder if there is a chef approach?

Comment: If you install your software using "normal" packages, there are [package](http://docs.opscode.com/resource_package.html) resources shipped with Chef. If you roll your own, you probably need to know where the version is stored on disk and write a provider for that. This is kinda advanced though.